# How to write binary file from hex string in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, binary, writefile

I want to make binary executable file from hex string in windows cmd. I used "echo" cmd command but it is written in 
 normal string, not binary format. So output exe file could not be executed.

```
input: "\x4d\x5a\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\..." (this is first part of PE)
output: binary executable file
```

Is it possible in windows cmd? If possible, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it is not. There is nothing in CMD to convert hex to viruses.

Comment: @user12431753: Of course cmd can make binary files from hex. Remember Détente after the rise of nuclear weapons? I presume you don't want a reduction in proliferation of viruses, and that opensource software should be banned in favor of monopolies and inequality of the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: there is the tool named [`CertUtil.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) (available since Windows XP, though some verbs may have been altered), which features a verb called `-decodehex` (for the optional parameter `type` take a look at the argument `dwFlags` of the function [`CryptBinaryToStringA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa)):

> ```cmd
> Usage:
>   CertUtil [Options] -decodehex InFile OutFile [type]
>   Decode hexadecimal-encoded file
>     type -- numeric CRYPT_STRING_* encoding type
> [...]
> ```

However, this does not understand the hex codes of your input data, the `\x` need to be removed.

---

The following script reads your input hex string from a file, replaces every `\x` by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in a temporary file and converts this to a binary file using `certutil -decodehex`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_INPF=%~1" & rem // (input file; `%~1` is first command line argument)
set "_OUTF=%~2" & rem // (output file; `%~2` is second command line argument)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (temporary file)

rem // Prepare input file by replacing `\x` with ` ` and writing result to temp. file:
< nul set /P ="Preparing data... "
< "%_INPF%" > "%_TMPF%" call :PREPARE
echo done.
rem // Convert temporary file with hex codes into binary output file:
certutil -f -v -decodehex "%_TMPF%" "%_OUTF%" 4
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%_TMPF%"

endlocal
exit /B


:PREPARE
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Initialise auxiliary variables:
    set "REST="
    rem /* Read input file in chunks of 1 KBytes using `set /P`; `for /F` is avoided
    rem    for reading the file, because it would limit line lengths to 8 KBytes: */
:PREPARE_LOOP
    rem // Read a chunk or line of hex codes:
    set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
    rem // Read chunk is empty, hence end of data is reached, so terminate loop:
    if not defined LINE goto :PREPARE_NEXT
    rem // Prepend potential fragment from previous chunk:
    set "LINE=!REST!!LINE!" & set "REST="
    rem // Now replace every `\x` by ` `:
    set "LINE=!LINE:\x= !"
    rem // Store remaining fragment of search string to be processed with next chunk:
    if "!LINE:~-1!"=="\" (set "LINE=!LINE:~,-1!" & set "REST=\")
    rem /* Return converted chunk without trailing line-break in order to avoid hex
    rem    codes to become torn apart: */
    < nul set /P ="!LINE!"
    rem // Loop back at this point:
    goto :PREPARE_LOOP
:PREPARE_NEXT
    endlocal
    exit /B
```

Note that `certutil` limits file sizes to a few dozens of MBytes (as also mentioned [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8521)).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but I think that was possible in the old DOS debug.  Take a look here: https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/DOS-Debug.shtml

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to use any other tool, just using windows cmd.

Comment: `Debug` can be run from `cmd`, just like `certutil`, `forfiles`, `findstr`, `doskey`, `ping` etc

Answer (score 1):

```
set input=\x4d\x5a\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff

del out.exe
echo la >t
set input=%input:\x= %
fsutil file createnew 0 1
chcp 1252 >nul

for %i in (%input%) do (

if /i %i==ff (
set /p=ÿ<nul>> out.exe

) else (

if %i==00 (
type 0 >> out.exe

) else (
forfiles /m "t" /c "cmd /c set /p=0x%i>> out.exe"< nul

)
)

)
```

Some bytes need escaping to work with `forfiles`; a workaround is to find 'the poison characters', then generate the bytecodes from different characters in different codepages, before generating the binary file eg. 437 vs 1252 give different byte for same char: ÿ - 0x98 vs 0xFF

```
dir out.exe

14/10/2021  12:31                14 out.exe
               1 File(s)             14 bytes
```

Tested on Win 10 cmd.